# Error in callback doesn't display error info

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Sails.js 1.0.2

Hi. I try to debug an error in a callback but the only message is this one:

````
    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    WARNING: Something seems to be wrong with this function.
    It is trying to signal that it has finished AGAIN, after
    already resolving/rejecting once.
    (silently ignoring this...)

    To assist you in hunting this down, here is a stack trace:

    ```
    at /node/zg-sails-v1/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/do-with-connection.js:242:28
    at /node/zg-sails-v1/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/do-with-connection.js:123:18
    at Object.success (/node/zg-sails-v1/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/build-std-adapter-method.js:61:47)
    at /node/zg-sails-v1/node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:1509:30
    at proceedToFinalAfterExecLC (/node/zg-sails-v1/node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:1151:14)
    at proceedToInterceptsAndChecks (/node/zg-sails-v1/node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:909:12)
    at proceedToAfterExecSpinlocks (/node/zg-sails-v1/node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:841:10)
    at /node/zg-sails-v1/node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:303:7
    at /node/zg-sails-v1/node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:964:24
    at Function.handlerCbs.success (/node/zg-sails-v1/node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:824:26)
    at findCb (/node/zg-sails-v1/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/machines/find-records.js:138:20)
    at handleCallback (/node/zg-sails-v1/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:120:56)
    at /node/zg-sails-v1/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:860:16
    at handleCallback (/node/zg-sails-v1/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:171:5)
    at setCursorDeadAndNotified (/node/zg-sails-v1/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:505:3)
    at nextFunction (/node/zg-sails-v1/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:651:7)
    at Cursor.next [as _next] (/node/zg-sails-v1/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:692:3)
    at fetchDocs (/node/zg-sails-v1/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:856:10)
    at /node/zg-sails-v1/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:879:7
    at handleCallback (/node/zg-sails-v1/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:171:5)
    at nextFunction (/node/zg-sails-v1/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:682:5)
    at /node/zg-sails-v1/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:593:7
    ```
````

I only want to display error infos. There's a stack trace following but it doesn't help me.

Here an example of my code:

```
User.find({id: id}).exec((err, user) => {
  if (err) {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
    console.log(myUndefinedVar);
  }
});
```

It's a legacy project with hundred of callbacks, so I can't refactor all the code with await, try / catch.

Thanks.

EDIT: Stacktrace added

---

EDIT: new example, eslint doesn't hang out.

```
Game.find({id: req.session.gameID}).exec((err, objGame) => {
    if (err) {
        utilService.newLog('error', stackTrace, __line, 'Game.find({id: req.session.gameID: ' + req.session.gameID + ' ...');
        utilService.newLog('error', stackTrace, __line, err);
        return res.redirect('dashboard');
    } else if (typeof objGame === 'undefined') {
        utilService.newLog('error', stackTrace, __line, 'objGame === undefined ...');
        utilService.newLog('error', stackTrace, __line, err);
        return res.redirect('dashboard');
    } else {
        ...
    }
});
```

This

```
Game.find({id: req.session.gameID}).exec((err, objGame) => {
```

objGame is an array

```
    } else if (typeof objGame === 'undefined') {

    ... 

    jsfiles = sails.config.gameCfg[objGame.type].dev.jsfiles;
```

Must be

```
    } else if (typeof objGame[0] === 'undefined') {
```

Because objGame[0] is undefined

No error is displayed, just the WARNING.

Comment: Add the `stacktrace` too. Just found out, there are numerous issues open on `sails` github repo about this error.

Comment: EDIT: Stacktrace added

And replied to this issue open sails github repo https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/4502

Comment: If you're using Chrome and open the DevTools Console during the error, you should have the full error code. Click the gray "Show #### More" in the lower right and scroll to the bottom for a highlighted point of error (though it may not always be the exact issue but certainly related).  Also trying `sails run lint` in the terminal for your project - this can reveal where the issue exists too.

Comment: Same infos with DevTools Console, the same stack trace (local env).

Ok for the lint debug.
I did it with the vscode ESlint addon.
I'll try it with the next same problem. Thanks.

Comment: Edit with another example where lint doesn't hang out.

Comment: @Paul If you are using VS Code as editor then you try adding debugger and find out where the problem is.

Comment: Paul, I really recommend upgrading to await.  I know it's a chore, but it is leaps and bounds better for the stability, security, and maintainability of your application.  If you need help convincing anyone else on your team, let me know on Twitter and I'll be happy to jump in.

Comment: Hi and thanks you all for your comments.

@khushalbokadey Your advice is good, I'm a VS code user, so I tried to add a debuguer and it works well. But too many errors stop the execution, I can find the ones that interest me but it takes a lot of time and I have to restart the application and the debugger every time I make a change. Maybe I'm not familiar enough with this debugger. I will vote for your answer if it was not a comment.

Comment: @mikermcneil Thank you for your reply, it's cool to see you answer questions. I agree that in the long run it's the best thing to do and following your advice that's what we're going to do. It's a chore but our project is a succession of chores, we are used to it. It's a big project but it's still in development, we have time. Thanks again.

Comment: @Paul Good to know that it worked for you. BTW you can upvote the comment itself. I would’nt consider my advice as answer.

Comment: @ khushalbokadey I can't for the moment, I don't have the 15 Reputation needed

Answer (score 0):

Had these errors so many times. Helped just one thing - switching all callbacks into async functions. Then i can see the errors.

Wrong:

```
function some_method() {
  User.find().limit(1).exec(function(err, users) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    console.log(users[1].id)
    // i will get the error "WARNING: Something..."
    // because i am querying just 1 User, and trying to log second user 
  });
}
```

Good:

```
async function some_method() {
  var users = await User.find().limit(1);
  console.log(users[1].id)
  // i will see the exact error , which shows exactly where is the problem
  // and say, that i am trying to read property id of undefined.
  // You dont even need to console the Errors - it does it automatically!
}
```

But if your whole project is full with callbacks,  what at least helps is to spot when the problems appears. As this message is not helping to know where at all is the problem. It can be anywhere in the whole project. What you can do - is **Temporary** deal with those prolems until you replace all your code from callback to async.

> 1) create Logging system. Log every request. I am using winston.
>   Logging every request, writing request time with milliseconds.
>   If you use pm2, dont write these request logs into console, because then you cant see when the real error occurs.

Next:

> 2) overwrite this WARNING to write the time when did it appear. Go to
>   `node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deffered.js`, there are 2 places
>   where this WARNING is written. replace it to:  `(new Date()) + '---' +
>   (new Date().getTime()) + '---WARNING: Something seems to be wrong with
>   this function...`

So now you can at least know which request is buggy. If the project is almost abandoned, this way helps. But if the project is active, you should just rewrite every method into async await. I am already 6 months into this - rewriting the whole backend into async-await and it helps really well - code is much nicer, all errors very clear.